# Surjectivity of  homomorphism of sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\phi : \mathcal F \to \mathcal G$ be a homomorphism of quasicoherent sheaves on a scheme $X$. What are the necessary properties of the scheme $X$, so that in order to show the surjectivity of $\phi$, would it be enough to show the surjectivity of $\phi$ on stalks only for closed points of $X$ ?

Comment: Why "necessary", not "sufficient"? Passing to coker, for sufficiency it's same to ask for sufficient conditions so q-coh sheaf with vanishing stalks at all closed points is 0. Every q-coh sheaf on a q-compact q-separated scheme is the direct limit of q-coh subsheaves of finite type, so enough to treat the latter case. Then the sheaf vanishes on *open* around any pt where stalk vanishes, so suffices that open containing all closed pts is  whole space; i.e., a *non-empty* closed set has a closed pt. True in any q-c scheme (EGA 0$_{\rm{I}}$, 2.1.3; I, 2.1.4). So "q-compact, q-sep'td" suffices. 

Comment: A separate comment: I don't know the motivation for the question, but unless it is the role of closed pts in proof of Serre's cohomological criterion for affineness, I recommend letting go from attachment to closed pts when away from classical-type situations (such as loc. finite type over a field) because the property of a pt being closed is not local (e.g., consider generic pt in spec of dvr). I was told that there are schemes without closed pts, but it doesn't really matter: in general non-local schemes, "closed pt" is not such an important concept (unlike classical cases).